# Java System.in and System.out differ between Sun/Oracle and IBM JVMs - solutions to read write standard byte array

Tags: java, encoding, system.out

**In Java, is there any way to control the file encoding of System.in and System.out?**

Sun/Oracle uses:

`java.io.BufferedInputStream - Stdin
 java.io.PrintStream - Stdout`

IBM uses:

`com.ibm.jvm.io.ConsoleInputStream - Stdin
 com.ibm.jvm.io.ConsolePrintStream - Stdout`

The problem comes to light with the IBM jvm, where outputting the data byte array in hex gives: 308209d606092... (just before writing to System.out)

but reading in the same file and writing out as hex gives: 303f09d606092a3f48...

Sun/Oracle shows the same hex value.

Is there any way to control these inputs or cut back to an underlying common input/output stream? System.out is a final, and the implementation seems to depend on the JVM.

*More generally is the use of redirection a consistent way to transfer text/binary data between applications?*

Any code which shows how to normalise input/output data to/from System.in/out appreciated. Using Commons-IO IOUtils to read/write the streams to byte arrays.

Comment: While it's true that `System.out` is `final`, there is also a magic `System.setOut(PrintStream)` method that can change it (there is also a `System.setIn(InputStream)`). You can change them to a stream of your own choosing if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with IBM JDK for a long time, but here stroke me something. There's difference between Stream and Reader. The reader effectively tries to en(de)code byte array to chars and they are not the same. There may be difference default encoding between the JVM providers.

So I'd suggest

- encode the byte array (e.g. base64) to have it as chars and it should give you pretty same results through runtimes regardless you use reader or stream
- use stream only - effectively transferring binary data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I think I already write to the stream. I'm currently looking at ConsolePrintStream's source code to see if this provides any options.

Comment: Tried wrapping:                                                                                                                                                                                      outputStream = new WriterOutputStream(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "ISO-8859-1"));

                                                                                    
inputStream = new ReaderInputStream(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "ISO-8859-1"));                                                                                                                 but this hasn't worked. Hmm.

Comment: According your output only the "82" char has been changed (what is a non-printable char), though I believe the in/output stream should not change it to support binary streaming, but for console it may have its reasons. IMHO if you have control over both parts, I'd suggest to encode the data (base64, hex..).